# Ansible / Jinja2 get item filer

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Assume I have a list of:

```
vpcs:
  - name: myvpc1
    description: bla
    zone: Enterprise
    cidr: "10.5.0.0/16"

  - name: vpc2
    description: bla
    zone: Private
    cidr: "10.6.0.0/16"
```

I would like to select the zone of `vpc1`. So the filter below should return
`Enterprise`

My actual filter

```
{{ vpcs | selectattr('name', 'match', 'myvpc1') | first | attr('zone') }}
```

Does not work due to:

> Get an attribute of an object. foo|attr("bar") works like foo.bar just
>   that always an attribute is returned and items are not looked up.

So it says `key not found`

How would I describe this filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the filter to the below, so it grabs the value of zone.

```
  tasks:
    -  set_fact:
         myvar: "{{ (vpcs | selectattr('name', 'match', 'myvpc1') | first)['zone'] }}"

    - debug: var=myvar
```

The reason for this can be found in [this](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/24065) Ansible's github issue, answered by jctanner (Member of Ansible)

Comment: Yes, the reason is that the dictionary keys it's not the same as dictionary attributes. attr() only returns the attributes of the object.

Comment: @IgnacioMillán that's the quote in my question. It is just strange that there seems to be no filter for `getitem`